# How to avoid multiple calls to findViewById() in Adapter class?

Tags: android, performance, android-adapter, findviewbyid

I am trying to speed up an app as much as possible by calling `findViewById()` as little as possible in the Adapter class.

I've heard of a "way" where I can create a `HashMap<T>` containing `View` instances and integers as values, and use it along or together with adapter's `ViewHolder` inner class. As you can see, I heard very little about this and did not have chance to ask more questions about this "way".

I have been searching for the solution on the Internet, but I am either searching using the wrong keywords or I am not recognizing solutions as such.

Can anyone direct me in a right way? Maybe someone writing a small sample on how to accomplish this?

EDIT 1

I don't have any issues with my current `ListView` as it's already using `ViewHolder` pattern. The reason for this question was because I heard that you can actually gain more speed using `HashMap` pattern than using `ViewHolder` pattern. I know this is vague description, but that's why I came here to ask.

Sharing a code would not help at all, because it's just a regular adapter using `ViewHolder` pattern, just like the one in the links you shared. There is no any experimenting or something that made the adapter slow.

Saying it again, the main reason to ask this was to find our if there is a pattern faster than the `ViewHolder`

Comment: Um, if you are already using a `ViewHolder`, and if the `ViewHolder` is written properly, you already have minimized your `findViewById()` calls.

Comment: post some code so we can see what you already have

Comment: Your mind might be set up on this, but did you consider  stepping back and actually measuring if there's a performance problem with using findViewById() as you are currently? You might spend a lot of time doing this optimization, and in the end it can turn out you gained almost literally nothing, but uglified your code instead :)

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, it uses `ViewHolder` and I thought that was it. But then I heard about "even better approach" where I can map IDs into `HashMap` and then iterate through it, because `HashMap` is way faster than `findViewById()`. So I am trying to figure out the concept of this better way using `HashMap`.

Comment: "I heard that you can actually gain more speed using HashMap pattern than using ViewHolder pattern" -- citation, please. It is possible that this is incrementally faster to *code*, as you don't have to mess with creating your own `ViewHolder`. But otherwise you are claiming that accessing objects in a `HashMap` is faster than is accessing fields on an object, and I highly doubt that this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

The way to reduce the *amount* of calls to findViewById is to "recycle" Views with ViewHolder. The idea behind is to keep inflated views and reuse them when needed - and since they already have ViewHolders you don't need to make the findViewById calls.

As @nhaarman described in the last part of his answer the way to do it for listviews is in the getView to reuse the convertView if it's not null and using the referenced view in the ViewHolder to update them.

An approach how to create ViewHolder and store them in the View by setTag is described in the [first link](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) @nhaarman provided. 
Then in the getView function if convertView isn't null call the getTag inorder to get the ViewHolder back.

In another note, you should look into [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) which is a listview that enforces the ViewHolder pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the ViewHolder paradigm which is most easily implemented with [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) when Adapters are involved. Online sample code available [here](https://developer.android.com/samples/RecyclerView/project.html) and GitHub sample cloneable via AndroidStudio directly or [via Github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RecyclerView).

The HashMap solution will work, but why incur a HashMap lookup when you can simply hold a reference to the object? Also, RecyclerView natively handles different View TYPEs so you don't have to roll your own solution when you have section header rows which look differently from data rows.

===============================================

A more detailed explanation of `RecyclerView` follows based on snippets from the sample I linked to.

Have your `CustomAdapter` extend `RecyclerView`.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
```

Create a Custom `ViewHolder` class. It should almost always be a static class if embedded within your `CustomAdapter`.

```
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View.
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Element " + getPosition() + " clicked.");
                }
            });
            textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Notice that the `ViewHolder` finds the views in the constructor since a `ViewHolder` instance is tied to a `View` instance. The `ViewHolder` should have references to any UI elements that you plan to update in an `onBind` callback. The `ViewHolder` object is then associated with the `View` by `RecyclerView` when you include the following code in your `CustomAdapter`.

```
// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    // Create a new view.
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.text_row_item, viewGroup, false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
```

Notice how the `onCreateViewHolder` callback is given a `viewType` parameter. The current code always returns the same type of custom `ViewHolder`, but it could be providing different ViewHolder classes based on the type (this is how you support rows that support different views). The following code is then how you update your UI when the view is bound to a dataset.

```
// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Element " + position + " set.");

    // Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the contents of the view
    // with that element
    viewHolder.getTextView().setText(mDataSet[position]);
}
```

With these pieces in place `RecyclerView` will create and reuse your `Views` AND `ViewHolders` by corresponding type reducing view hierarchy look ups and potentially making your app much less "janky".

Comment: When I use `RecyclerView`, I am doing the same :). What do you mean by `... when you can simply cache references`

Comment: Updated my answer to be much more specific.

Comment: Thanks. Already doing the exactly same thing :). I guess there is not faster way as CommonsWare says. Who are we to doubt him :).

Comment: If you're following this pattern then you're at 1 findViewById() call per view created and as long as you're not preventing view recycling you should focus optimization efforts elsewhere.